# Estimation fractional Sobolev norm by Littlewood-Paley projection

Tags: harmonic-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $1 < p < \infty$, $s > 0$, $f\in S'(\mathbb{R}^d)$ with sobolev norm
$\|f\|_{W^{s, p}} = \|(1-\Delta)^{s/2}f\|_p = \|(1 + 4\pi^2 |\xi|^2)^{s/2} \hat{f}(\xi))^\check{} \|_p$.

We need to prove that $\|f\|_{W^{s, p}} \sim \|P_{\le 0} f\|_p + \|(\sum_{j > 0} 2^{2js} |P_j f|^2)^{1/2}\|_p$, where $P_{\le 0}$ and $P_j$ is Littlewood-Paley projection.

It is relatively straightforward to prove for pseudodifferential operator $\Delta^{s/2}$, however I am confused how to prove the case $(1-\Delta)^{s/2}$, although my lecture notes said it is trivial.